# How to change size of imagebutton in android programatically

Tags: java, android, resize, imagebutton

I have to create few buttons imagebuttons programatically and i don't know how to change size of them. Changing left and right does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Use this.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 80;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 200;//set appropriate sizes
imageView.getLayoutParams().width= 200;
imageView.requestLayout();//this line redraws the imageview again call only after you set the size
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here if you want to change the size of the button, you have to change the xml code here it goes.

     <FrameLayout                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">           
            <Button     android:id="@+id/saveSearchButton"  android:layout_width="50dp"         android:layout_height="50dp" />
            <ImageView                                      android:layout_width="45dp"         android:layout_height="45dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_save" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">           
            <Button     android:id="@+id/clearSearchButton" android:layout_width="50dp"         android:layout_height="50dp" />
            <ImageView                                      android:layout_width="45dp"         android:layout_height="45dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

---

```
//ImageView Setup
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

//setting height and width of imageview
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//setting margins around imageimageview
`params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);` //left, top, right, bottom

//adding attributes to the imageview
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: But it is about button not just simple image, is it still the same way?

Comment: i have include the xml code which will help you @qwkldmas

Answer (score 0):

```
imgbtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

or :

```
imgbtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 100));
```