# How to change imagesize dynamically

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I have defined imageview size in xml file. So, it will takes it as default when image appear. I'm displaying different images based on some condition. So, i need to change the image widht and height.

xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"        
        android:visibility="invisible"  />
```

Java:

```
if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {                      
      image.setImageResource(R.drawable.y); 

      }                    
    else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("z")) {
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.z); // Here i need to change the width & height of the image
               }
```

Comment: lock at this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982432/how-to-change-size-of-imagebutton-in-android-programatically/24982508#24982508

Comment: why not use `wrap_content` dimensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
imgView.getLayoutParams().height = 300;
imgView.getLayoutParams().width= 300;
imgView.requestLayout();//changing width and height programmatically will require the view to be redrawn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
LayoutParams yourView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```